# embed and loop just a part of a youtube video (html5)

Tags: youtube, youtube-javascript-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to loop just a part of a YouTube video with the HTML5 player? I tried this code (start 7 sec, end 12sec)

The first "loop" shows the part I want, second and other loops shows the whole video.

It is working in Flash but I have issues in HTML 5 for mobile devices.

Here is my embed code:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"  width="960" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bpu0TIXzI1w?version=3&start=7&end=12&amp;autohide=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;loop=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playlist=Bpu0TIXzI1w"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to use the Javascript API. It's a bit more complex, but you have full control over the video playback.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pbosakov/Lo6gwtff/

Code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'Bpu0TIXzI1w',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    loopStart();
    player.playVideo();
}
function loopStart() {
    player.seekTo(7);   // Start at 7 seconds
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        setTimeout(loopStart, 5000); // After 5 seconds, restart the loop
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hmpf ok thanks... hoped my embed code was/is just wrong because i have to embed ~50-80 clips :/

Comment: Nope, it just does not seem to work with plain iframe embed. I'm not sure if that's a bug or intended behavior. But the API is powerful and you have many options to adapt it to your needs. Here is an improved version that works with multiple videos: http://jsfiddle.net/pbosakov/6gx5g7mz/10/

Comment: thank you much for your help. The only issue, its not working on mobile devices because of the autoplay option (to avoid high datatraffic). I changed the player.playVideo(); to player.stopVideo(); but after this changes the video wont loop anymore.